# Suitable distributions for the SDs of a number of groups (or participants)?

Tags: distributions, standard-deviation

When analyzing data, using MLE or Bayesian methods, one needs to assume  a distribution for the data. For continuous data the are a number of distributions that are often considered, for example, the normal distribution, the t-distribution, the log-normal, etc.

**When analyzing the distribution of the SDs of a number of groups (or participants) what distributions could be appropriate?** Of course this is dependent on the data, and varies from case to case, but what could be some reasonable distributions to try?

Answer (score 3):

In general, a [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) will be [distributed as chi-squared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution).